# Pass in env specific properties into a webapp

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, deployment

We are looking for deployment options for our continuous integration system for our webapp. We are building a single .war file. We need to deploy it across several different envs (e.g. DEV, QA, STAGE, etc). AFAIK, there are two ways to pass in the env specific properties:

First, use the -D option when starting Tomcat:

```
-Denv=DEV
```

This require us to customize the `catalina.sh` script for every env.

Second, use the environment variables before launching Tomcat:

```
export env=DEV;
```

This require us to tweak the deployment script for each env. And this is platform dependent (i.e. on Windows you'll have to do `set env=DEV`).

Can anyone tell me which of these two options is better? Or is there any other better ones?

Answer (score 0):

We have a web app which is deployed into 14 different environments.  To manage this, we create a unique build for each environment.

We are using maven as a build system, so each environment has a unique profile.  The profile references a properties file for filtering which contains configuration that varies across environments.  This information is tokenized into Spring context files, web.xml, weblogic.xml, etc.  (We do not filter source files as this gets ugly fast.)

The second piece of this is our Jenkins CI server.  We have a job for each environment which references the corresponding profile.  This points to a well-known tag name in our subversion repo.  So the flow goes like this:

1. Development happens and code committed to trunk.
2. Need to build into some env, so we create a tag called "latest" (removing old copies if they exist).  At the same time, we also create a tag with a date-time stamp, but this is optional.
3. Kick-off the appropriate hudson build.  This means we are not building off some developers workstation, and the build is already configured so there is nothing to remember.
4. Pull the artifact to deploy right out of Jenkins.

I've seen application configuration maintained within the app server itself, but unless you have something like [glu](http://linkedin.github.com/glu/docs/latest/html/index.html) to manage things, it quickly becomes a nightmare to maintain.  This is especially true if you have different teams for development and ops.

Comment: We are building off of Maven as well. But we would like to keep one build for all our envs. We designed our project in a way that all app config files resides outside of the war file (so that config changes won't trigger a Maven build). During deployment, we need to pass in the env name (DEV, QA, etc) into our app so that corresponding property files will be loaded.

Comment: 1) if you are staging config externally, why do you need an env identifier?  Wouldn't the appropriate config files for that env be the ones deployed there? 2) I've used the local hostname to identify the env before.  This implies you have a mapping table somewhere though.

Comment: We are trying to simplify the staging process. Instead of having the deployment script pick the appropriate env files to put in place, we are trying to always deploy the same set of env files (with all predefined envs), and then have the script tell the app which env this machine is. Maybe that is not the best solution. Now when I think about this, maybe only staging the files specific to that env should be a better way.